# get woocommerce product attributes in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I've got a custom post type named "department" and have some language course in it. and also have a woocommerce product for each department course for buying the courses. I use advanced custom field to relate the custom post type to each product. now I want to access my variation product attribute such as regular price and sale price IN THE CUSTOM POST TYPE.
I code this in my single-department.php:

```
$productID = get_field('product_buy_link');

foreach ($productID as $pID) {
$product = wc_get_product($pID->ID);
}

$fullPrice = array($product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true),             
$product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true));

$priceAfterDiscount = array($product->get_variation_regular_price('max', 
true), $product->get_variation_sale_price('max', true)); 

<?php foreach ($fullPrice as $fp) : ?>
<p><?php echo $fp . " - " ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach ($priceAfterDiscount as $pad) : ?>
<p><?php echo $pad  . " - " ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it only gives me two price (the max price and min price). this issue makes things wrong when for example:

product one: reg price = 1000$, sale price= 800$

product two: reg price = 1100$, sale price = 700$

in this situation output of codes above is :

product one: reg price = 1000$, sale price= 700$

product two: reg price = 1100$, sale price = 800$

which is wrong.

Comment: Do you expect `$productID = get_field('product_buy_link');` to be an array or an integer (a single product ID) ?

Comment: ACF relation for this field returns "Post Object". $product in line 3 returns the related course ID and it works fine. I get the variation names with this:                               https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/342998

Comment: I choose ACF to relate every product to specific post and get just single product ID